# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name

Tags: laravel-8

The following migration:

```
Schema::dropIfExists('personal_access_tokens');

Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->morphs('tokenable');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
    $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->index(['tokenable_type', 'tokenable_id']);
});
```

Results in the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key
> name 'personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index' (SQL:
> alter table `personal_access_tokens` add index
> `personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index`(`tokenable_type`,
> `tokenable_id`))

Why is this happening and how do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to drop the created index `tokenable_type` and `tokenable_id` in order to re-create the table.

```php
Schema::table('personal_access_tokens', function ($table) {
    $table->dropIndex(['tokenable_type', 'tokenable_id']); // Drops indexes
});
```

After you did that you can drop the table and create it again.